# Redshift Spectrum Performance vs Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a bucket in S3 with parquet files and partitioned by dates.

With the following query:

```
select
    count(1)
from logs.logs_prod
where partition_1 = '2019' and partition_2 = '03'
```

Running that query in Athena directly, it executes in less than 10 seconds. But when I run the same query in Redshift, it is taking over 3 minutes. Both of them return the same correct value and, in this case, there are less than 80 thousand rows in that partition.

I'm using AWS Glue as Metadata Store for both Athena and Redshift.

The query plan for Redshift is the following:

```
QUERY PLAN
XN Limit  (cost=250000037.51..250000037.51 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=250000037.51..250000037.51 rows=1 width=8)
        ->  XN Partition Loop  (cost=250000000.00..250000035.00 rows=1000 width=8)
              ->  XN Seq Scan PartitionInfo of logs.logs_prod  (cost=0.00..15.00 rows=1 width=0)
                    Filter: (((partition_1)::text = '2019'::text) AND ((partition_2)::text = '03'::text))
              ->  XN S3 Query Scan logs_prod  (cost=125000000.00..125000010.00 rows=1000 width=8)
                    ->  S3 Aggregate  (cost=125000000.00..125000000.00 rows=1000 width=0)
                          ->  S3 Seq Scan logs.logs_prod location:"s3://logs-prod/" format:PARQUET  (cost=0.00..100000000.00 rows=10000000000 width=0)
```

Is this issue a Redshift Spectrum configuration problem? Is it possible that the query in Redshift won't perform close to Athena?

Comment: I'm running into what looks like a similar issue. I have a very simple query on an external table with parquet files partitioned by a varchar and a date. I write a query targeting a single partition with a single parquet file, and it takes over a minute to return.

I don't want to answer with a question, so I apologize for formatting...


Query:
```SELECT uuid
FROM spectrum.telemetry_event
WHERE "tag" = 'my.test.tag'
  AND date = '2020-05-06';``` Query plan:  ```XN Partition Loop \n -> XN Seq Scan \n Filter \n -> XN S3 Query Scan \n -> S3 Seq Scan```

Comment: good read: https://blog.panoply.io/an-amazonian-battle-comparing-athena-and-redshift

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should put too much weight to this test. From the plan it looks like it's not taking advantage of the fact that Parquet files contain metadata about the number of rows in each file – which is something I believe Athena/Parquet can do.

The actual real world performance of Athena vs. Redshift Spectrum is difficult to measure since with Athena you don't know how much capacity you get (but it's a lot) and in Redshift Spectrum you get a dedicated capacity that is dependent on your cluster size. For Redshift clusters with ~20 CPUs I've found Athena to perform better for most queries, but larger Redshift clusters may get better performance.

Comment: This isn't a test, it is a real live problem. I use both Athena and Redshift for reporting, but Redshift with S3 isn't working well.

Comment: If you give us more examples of what's slow in Redshift perhaps we can help you even more. If all you do is counting the number of rows in the partitions it looks like Athena is going to be the better choice, but it seems unlikely to me that that is the only thing you are doing.

Comment: I'm just trying to extract some data from S3 through Redshift. I wanted to use this data to join in other tables that are in Redshift. A simple select or just this count isn't working well. The way this is, I'll have to extract data from Athena and insert into Redshift to execute this simple queries.

Comment: Added a similar query in a comment above, but I definitely am seeing consistent poor performance with my own double-partitioned table. A simple query that targets a single partition to read in a single parquet file takes anywhere from 1:20s to 3m.

Comment: One weird thing: When I query svl_s3query_summary, it says `elapsed` time is 1.851s, but it took 1m 36s to run...